# Customer custom attribute using EAV is not displaying values in Grid

Tags: backend, custom-attributes, entity-attribute-value, magento2.2

**Scenario**

I'm trying to implement a custom attribute for Magento Customer, that should accept **boolean** values (True/False, Yes/No...).
I'm using Magento CE 2.2.4.
This is part of a custom Module under `/app/code/TheVendor_TheModule/`.
The other components of the Module are working correctly.

---

**Expected Result**

- The attribute must be represented with a **switch** input or checkbox in back-end Customer form.
- The attribute and its values must appear in Customers Grid
- The attribute must appear in the **Filter** with selectable options (Yes/No or True/False or Is/Is not, any Boolean-like value works fine)

---

**Actual Result**

- [*OK*] A switch shows in the back-end within the Customer form as expected.
- [*OK*] Changing the switch value to on or off + saving works fine.
- [**Issue**] The attribute's `Label` shows in the **Customer Grid** but **the values are missing**.
- [**Issue**] The attribute's input in the **Filter** shows but **does not contain options**.

---

**Screens**

Customer Form View in back-end

[image: Customer Form View]

Customer Grid and Filter View

[image: Customer Grid and Filter View]

---

**Code**

```
<?php

namespace TheVendor\TheModule\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    const ATTRIBUTE_APPROVED = 'attribute_approved';

    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;
    private $attributeResource;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, 
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, 
        Config $eavConfig, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ){
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::ATTRIBUTE_APPROVED, [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Attribute Approved',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'position' => 9,
            'sort_order' => 9,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
            //'user_defined' => true, //commented because causing attribute fail on module install
            //'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            //'unique' => 0,
        ]);

        $myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::ATTRIBUTE_APPROVED);

        $myAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);

        $this->attributeResource->save($myAttribute);

        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

---

**Attempts and Tests**

I tried the following:

- Lookup solution in Magento Dev Docs
- Lookup solution on StackExchange
- Lookup solution on other forums
- Tweaking `$customerSetup->addAttribute(...)` options:

  - Set `'user_defined' => true`. When used, this one is causing the attribute setup to fail without errors.
  - Set `'default' => 0` and `'default' => '0'`
  - Set `'searchable' => true`
- Checked logs for errors, none found.
- Removed the Module folder and create it again before reinstall
- Executed `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- Executed `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

**Testing Routine**

For every test that I made I followed these steps to ensure Module is being installed correctly:

- Execute `php bin/magento module:disable TheVendor_TheModule`
- Remove records from database:

  - Delete Module record in `mage_setup_module`
  - Delete EAV record in `mage_eav_attribute`
- Make sure Module is disabled in `app/etc/config.php`
- Pull updated code
- Execute `php bin/magento module:enable TheVendor_TheModule`
- Execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- Execute `php bin/magento cache:clean`

---

**Question**

Anyone with suggestions on how to handle this or how to detect where the problem is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Solution:

Edit `addAttribute(...)` options in `app/code/TheVendor/TheModule/Setup/InstallData.php`

**Use source model `'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean'` with input `select`**

```
...

$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, self::ATTRIBUTE_APPROVED, [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Attribute Approved',

        /** [Solution] Changed from 'boolean' to 'select' */
        'input' => 'select',  

        /** [Solution] Use source model Boolean */
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean', 

        'default' => '0',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'system' => false,
        'position' => 9,
        'sort_order' => 9,
        //'user_defined' => true,
        //'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => true,
        'comparable' => true,
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
        //'unique' => 0,
   ]); 

...
```

---

**Screen**

[image: Success Screen]

Hope this helps!